# Key expansion in AES CTR mode

Tags: aes, cbc, ctr

While working with AES 256 in CBC mode, I learned that it requires Key Expansion - forward (for encryption) and reverse (for decryption).
Does AES CTR mode also requires such a step ? Or can the 256 bit key be used as is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When AES performs an encryption (or decryption) with a key, it internally converts the key into a series of *subkeys* (either 11, 13 or 15 subkeys, depending on whether you start with a 128 bit, 192 bit or 256 bit AES key).  This process is known as *key expansion* and needs to be done, whether you encrypt and decrypt.

And, yes, this needs to be done for AES-CTR (or any other mode of operation of AES).

Now, when AES is implemented in software, we usually generate the subkeys once (and store them in memory); in hardware, it is not uncommon to generate the subkeys on the fly in parallel with processing the AES block (because the logic to do this on-the-fly generation is cheaper for hardware than storing the subkeys).

Comment: When you're saying "in hardware it's cheaper to calculate than to store" do you mean that the required FPGA / ASIC logic for the expansion is more compact than storing  the pre-calculated 128 * 15 bits per AES256 key ?

Comment: @shaiko: I believe it might be.  In addition, some hardware (including the ones I dealt with) can deal with multiple keys; the on-chip hardware to store all those subkeys, or alternatively, to shuffle in the subkeys from off-chip, is rather more expensive than the on-the-fly computation.